# Can someone explain how arrays and scalars are handled in a Python code snippet

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, sqrt

I have this code snippet I am trying to understand that is in python. I don't understand how scalars operate on arrays in all cases. In most code I read it makes sense that operations work on each value of an array.

```
sig_sq_samples = beta*invgamma.rvs(alpha,size=n_samples)
var_norm = sqrt(sig_sq_samples/kN)
mu_samples = norm.rvs(mean_norm,scale=var_norm,size=n_samples)
```

I want to know how each line is functioning.  The reason being is that I don't have a linux machine setup with the library and thought someone may be able to help me understand this python code I have found in an article. I can not setup the environment in a reasonable amount of time.

```
invgamma.rvs() - returns an array of numeric values
beta - is a scalar value

sig_sq_samples (I'm assuming)- is an array of beta * each array value of 
what invgamma.rvs() function returns.  

var_norm - I have no idea what this value is supposed to be because 
the norm.rvs function underneath takes a scalar (scale=var_norm).
```

In short how is sqrt(siq_sq_samples/kn) with kN also a scalar returning back a scalar?  What is happening here? This one line is what is getting me.  Like I said earlier sig_sq_samples is an array. I hope I'm not wrong about that line that is producing sig_sq_samples. At one point or another the values being worked on are scalars. I am from c# where hard types are used and I have worked with scripting languages such as PERL where I had a lot of experience with what "shortcut" operations do.  Ex. C# does not allow you to multiply a scalar to an array.  I tried to look up how scalars work with arrays but it doesn't clarify this code to me. Anyone answering is more than welcome to look up the functions above in case I am wrong about anything. I put a lot of effort and I have many years of development experience. Either this code snippet is wrong or I'm just not seeing something real obvious.

Comment: "the norm.rvs function underneath takes a scalar" - what makes you think that? The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs) says "scale : array_like, optional".

Comment: I missed array_like. I must of seen default = 1 and assumed it was a scalar also if I had seen array_like I didn't know what that means when combined with default = 1. Please remember when your not used to a language its hard to imagine a default of 1 for an array.  I know some languages are very loosely typed. I am not going to start a war about loose typing and hard typing but it sure makes it harder when your exposed to a new language when its not hard typed. Documentation should clarify scalar or array. I have no idea what array_like meant.

Comment: The saying in Python is: if it quacks like a duck it is a duck.  In many contexts a scalar (single number) can act like an array of numbers - just repeated the necessary of number times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
mu_samples = norm.rvs(mean_norm,scale=var_norm,size=n_samples)
```

`n_samples` has the same size as `var_norm`, so what is happening is that for the ith sample of `n_samples`, it generates it using the ith scale parameter of `var_norm`, `var_norm[i]`

Internal to the code is
`vals = vals * scale + loc`, when scale is an array it uses broadcasting which is a common feature of numpy. `norm.rvs` already generated an array of `n_samples` random values. When multiplied by `scale`, it does an element-wise multiplication between each array. The result is that the left hand side will also be an array value. For more information see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Comment: So what you are saying is that var_norm is in fact an array. I looked up the norm.rvs and it was a scalar and I think thats what got me stumped.

Comment: It can be both! If it is a scalar, every output of `norm.rvs` is generated with a constant scale, otherwise each output is made from individual scales in the scale array.

Comment: When you say "every output is from individual scales in the scale array" it is still a little confusing.  I don't see a definition of what happens when scale is an array.  My understanding is the size parameter returns an array of that size. So how can scale also define the size of the array or is every sample from a different scale? Is ith return value is a sample with ith scale??

Comment: Sorry didn't have enough time to edit my comment above time ran out. Here goes a reword of the comment: 

When you say "every output is from individual scales in the scale array" it is still a little confusing.  I don't see a definition of what happens when scale is an array.  My understanding is the rvs function will return an array "size" long. So how can scale also define the size of the array or is every sample from a different scale? If I understand correctly then ith return value is a sample with ith scale based on broadcasting?

Comment: @samman yes, the ith return value is a sample with the ith scale. Try playing around with broadcasting. In the case of a single number for the scale parameter, the scales are all identical. Internal to the rvs function, it will create an array of length (size), which is then multiplied by the scale parameter. If scale is an array, it does array element multiplication. If scale is a scalar, it multiples them all by a constant.

Answer (score 0):

```
sig_sq_samples = beta*invgamma.rvs(alpha,size=n_samples)
```

if 
    invgamma.rvs() - returns an array of numeric values
    beta - is a scalar value

then

```
sig_sq_samples = beta*invgamma.rvs(alpha,size=n_samples)
```

produces another array of the same size.  Scalar `beta` just multiplies each element.

In

```
var_norm = sqrt(sig_sq_samples/kN)
```

`kN` is scalar doing the same thing - dividing each element.  I assume `sqrt` is `numpy.sqrt`, which takes the sqrt of each element.  So `var_norm` is again an array of the original size (of `invgammas.rvs()`).

```
mu_samples = norm.rvs(mean_norm,scale=var_norm,size=n_samples)
```

I don't know what `norm.rvs` does, or where it is from.  It's not `numpy`, but could be a package in `scipy`.  I'd have to google it.  It takes one postional argument, here `mean_norm`, and two (at least) keyword values.  `n_samples` is probably a number, eg. 100.  But `scale` could certainly take an array, such as `var_norm`.

======================

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs

appears to be the documentation for the `rvs` method (`norm` is a subclass of `rv_continuous`).

Arguments are:

```
arg1, arg2, arg3,... : array_like
The shape parameter(s) for the distribution (see docstring of the instance object for more information).

scale : array_like, optional
Scale parameter (default=1).

size : int or tuple of ints, optional
Defining number of random variates (default is 1).
```

and the result is

```
rvs : ndarray or scalar
Random variates of given size.
```

I'm guessing `invgamma.rvs` is the similar method for a different subclass.  `alpha` must be the `shape` argument for the first, and `norm_mean` the shape for the 2nd.